# Why I'm getting weird array from another array in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, key-value

I've an array titled `$request_data` as follows :

```
Array
(
    [link] => http://www.yahoo.co.in
    [is_activity_feed] => 1
    [status_info] => my new yahoo link post
)
```

Then I'm creating a new array titled `$aVals` based on the above array as follows :

```php
$aVals['is_activity_feed']      = $request_data['is_activity_feed'];
$aVals['link']['description']   = $request_data['link']['description'];
$aVals['link']['image']         = $request_data['link']['default_image'];
$aVals['link']['title']         = $request_data['link']['title'];
$aVals['link']['url']           = $request_data['link']['link'];
$aVals['status_info']           = $request_data['status_info'];
$aVals["parent_user_id"]        = $request_data['group_id'];
$aVals["callback_item_id"]      = $request_data['group_id'];
$aVals["callback_module"]       = $request_data['callback_module'];
$aVals["group_id"]              = $request_data['group_id'];
```

Now upon executing the statement `print_r($aVals);` I get following weird array:

```
Array
(
    [is_activity_feed] => 1
    [link] => Array
        (
            [description] => h
            [image] => h
            [title] => h
            [url] => h
        )

    [status_info] => my new yahoo link post
    [parent_user_id] => 
    [callback_item_id] => 
    [callback_module] => 
    [group_id] => 
)
```

From the above output I'm not understanding why the below array is coming with **h** values even the respective array keys**(description, title, image ,url)** are absent in the array `$request_data`.

Ideally in below [link] array all the keys should contain `null` values:

```
[link] => Array
(
    [description] => h
    [image] => h
    [title] => h
    [url] => h
)
```

Please explain me from where and how this **'h'** letter is coming and setting as a value for each key in above inner array. It would be of great help to me.

Please guide me in this regard. Where I'm going wrong? What changes I need to make to my code?

Thanks. Waiting for your precious replies.

Answer (score 0):

The key `description` doesn't exist in `$request_data['link']`. It evaluates to 0 and therefore it is basically saying `$request_data['link'][0]`.

You should be seeing a warning (if you have errors displaying):

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in - on line X
```

---

It sets the value to `h` because that's the first letter (or character 0) of the value `http://www.yahoo.co.in`.

Effectively `$request_data['link'][0] == substr($request_data['link'],0,1)`

---

Try checking if the key is set before trying to access it:

```
if (isset($request_data['link']['description'])) {
    $aVals['link']['description'] = $request_data['link']['description'];
} else {
    $aVals['link']['description'] = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what possible values your array can take (when building your **$aVals** you seem to know the indexes) I would do something like this to initialize the array to some expected values (*based on your example keys*):

```
$request_data = array_fill_keys(array('link', 'is_activity_feed', 'status_info', 'status_info', 'group_id', 'callback_module'), null);
$request_data['link'] = array();
$request_data['link'] = array_fill_keys(array('description', 'default_image', 'title', 'link'), null);
```

So when you access any key, you know previously that it have been initialized to `null` and filled later (or not).

Ideally, depending on your usecase, I would even create an object so it's easier to handle more complicated cases, but this depends entirely on your usage.